# Finding $E(X)$ from an Indicator Function

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

$X$ is a random variable having pmf

$c(4−x)$$I_{\{−1,2,3\}}$$(x)$, for some constant $c$. Give the value of $E(X)$.

**Start at a Solution:**

It is my understanding that an indicator function is $1$ when a certain criteria holds. I think the notation in the question means that the criteria holds when $x = -1$, $ x = 2$, $ x = 3$.

Then $X$ = $I_{-1}$ + $I_2$ + $I_3$ = $c(4-(-1)) + c(4-2) + c(4-3)$ = $8c$.

I don't know where I'm going with this attempted solution. I'm really confused about indicator functions.

Comment: So find the value of $c $ (sum of probabilities equal 1). Then find the expected value in the 'usual' way.

Comment: $X $ is not the sum of the indicator functions, from what I can see.

Comment: You're probably right. I'm looking online and must be getting things mixed up.

Comment: But $c$ would be $1/8$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that $X = 8c$ (that doesn't make sense - $X$ is a random variable, not a constant) but that calculation you did will help you solve the problem.

You're right that $I_{\{-1,2,3\}}(x)$ is one if $x=-1,2,$ or $3$ and zero otherwise. So what is meant is that the distribution of $X$ obeys $$ P(X = -1) = c(4--1)=5c,\\ P(X = 2) = c(4-2) = 2c,\\ P(X=3) = c(4-3) = c$$ and $P(X\ne -1,2 \;\text{or}\; 3) = 0.$

So you know that $$ 1 = P(X=-1) + P(X=2) + P(X=3) = 8c$$ and thus $c=1/8.$

Now to compute $E(X)$ you take $$ (-1)P(X=-1) + 2P(X=2)+3P(X=3).$$

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now. I'm getting $E(X)$ = $.25$.